# How many collective nouns for animal groups exist in Portuguese?

Tags: tradução-inglês, origem-histórica, substantivos

How many collective nouns for animal groups exist in Portuguese?

Are they as many as the ones in [this list](http://www.thealmightyguru.com/Pointless/AnimalGroups.html)? If not, what is the reason that justifies this difference?

---

Quantos coletivos para grupos de animais existem no português?

Serão tantos como os [coletivos que existem em inglês](http://www.thealmightyguru.com/Pointless/AnimalGroups.html)? Se assim não for, qual a razão que justifica esta diferença?

### Edit

I realized through [Centaurus' answer](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1737/156) (which links to a [list in wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivo_coletivo)) that there are probably less than 30 collective nouns for animal groups. Following [ANeves suggestion](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/157/aneves), my intention with this question is to understand how many of them really exist and why there are so few compared to English.

Comment: Armfoot, até a própria resposta ficou partida em dois porque era longa demais... parece-me claramente uma pergunta "demasiado abrangente" ou "demasiado grande". (`There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.`)

Comment: @ANeves with the answers below I just related the nouns in both languages. However, the actual number of the nouns that exist in Portuguese seems to be much smaller (less than 30), which would all fit in a small answer. That is what I tried to focus on with this question: a simple comparison and to understand why the difference is so great (I can delete the answers and rephrase the question if this is not clear enough).

Comment: Hmm... that is true, @Armfoot, maybe an answer to the question made could be, simply: "Many, about 30. And no, much much less than in English."

Answer (score 1):

Collective nouns, and more specifically terms of venery*, are found in almost any language. Some languages such as English have a huge number of them. I can't tell you how many there are in Portuguese but you can find a short list [**here.**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivo_coletivo)  In a large country like Brazil, you are likely to find more than one collective noun for the same object. **What is the importance of a "collective noun"?** I wouldn't put too much emphasis on that. I know quite a few but there are many I never heard. The average Brazilian is likely to know not more than a dozen. In a nutshell, you don't have to know them all to be proficient in Portuguese.

> Here are some collective nouns most brazilians know:
>
> - cardume (peixes)
> - enxame (abelhas)
> - cacho (uvas, bananas)
> - arquipélago (ilhas)
> - esquadra (navios)
> - esquadrilha (aviões)
> - bando (pássaros, ladrões, pessoas, etc)
> - ninhada (filhotes)

* collective nouns for groups of animals.